# Using cookies to display number of times user has visited website in PHP

Tags: php, html

So I'm fairly new to PHP and I've written up my first code to basically create two cookies to track the time the user last opened the website and a counter.

I want my website to display the time the person last opened up the website, with a counter saying "it's the $cookieValue you've visited us!".

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    $cookieValue = 1;

    setcookie("time", $cookieValue, time()+(86400*365));

    $cookieLastVisit = null;

    setcookie("lastVisit", $cookieLastVisit, time()+(86400*365));
    ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Question 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if (!isset($_COOKIE["time"])){
        echo ("Welcome to my webpage! It is the first time that you are here.");

        $visit = date(DATE_RFC1036);
        setcookie("lastVisit", $visit);
    }
    else {
        $cookieValue = ++$_COOKIE["time"];

        echo("Hello, this is the " . $cookieValue . " time that you are visiting my webpage. Last time you visited my webpage on: " . $cookieLastVisit);

        $visit = date(DATE_RFC1036);
        setcookie("lastVisit", $visit);
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I've finished my code but can't grasp why when I open my website, absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: Set cookies are only present on the next request. So you'd have to reload the page to see the value. Not to mention that cookies are present in the header(s), which **have** to be sent before **any** output is generated. You need to remove the `<!DOCTYPE html>` from your php script.

Comment: @Darren the set cookies are basically for next time the user visits the page. So when I reload, it should increment my cookie and display the final value.

Comment: Read the [**Documentation for `setcookie()`**](http://php.net/setcookie), No output can be present before you set the headers.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put all setcookie() function calls at the top of the page, before any output is sent to the browser.